# How to send unquoted text as a parameter in Pyodbc?

Tags: pyodbc

Suppose I want to execute the following SQL statement using Pyodbc

```
Select col1 from Example_Table
```

The column is initially unknown.So I am trying to send the column name as a parameter into the SQL statement.So i tried running the following statement.

```
Cursor.execute("Select ? from Example_Table",("col1",))
```

But this is fetching something like this

```
[('col1',),('col1',),('col1',).....]
```

Whenever I pass a string as a parameter it ends up with single quotation marks while querying(That's what I think is happening).I know that using `%s` instead of 
`?` would be giving the results I want, but i can't use `%s` for my purposes.Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always concat the same type in python. You can concat the variable in query string as below:

```
Cursor.execute("Select "+ yourColumnVariable +" from Example_Table")
```